# Highcharts hover bug - with video to demonstrate

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, highcharts

I recently posted an issue regarding unpredictable hover on points in Highcharts, but the question didn't get much traction. Probably because it's difficult to explain.

I now posted a video here

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LovfLWpVVtc

showing this behavior.

It happens both on Chrome and Firefox (the video was done on FF on a high spec MacPro).

The video was done using this JsFiddle from the docs.

http://jsfiddle.net/HnwbQ/1/

As you can see, when approaching the first or last point from outside of the chart, no tootlip is shown. However if the cursor enters the chart and then approaches the first/last point, then a tooltip is rendered. This is erratic, and sometimes a tooltip is rendered when coming from the outside, sometimes it's not.

Any ideas what's the issue?

**MORE INFO**

This seems to occur mostly when using `xAxis: {type: 'datetime'},`

I am using Highcharts v2.1.9.

Comment: A solution would be to add more space to the graph - you can see the edge data points not being rendered completely due to not enough space.

Comment: i tried that without success - did not you notice that despite the tooltip not showing, the marker and line blink a state change? it looks like it's the tooltip alone that fails to render.

Comment: Easiest solution is not to worry about it. It's not ideal but users will quickly work out how to overcome this minor bug - ie. to approach the end points from inside the chart. Personally, I wouldn't be losing any sleep.

Comment: beetroot, this may seem like nitpicking on my part, but I need ALL points to be reliably rendered with tooltip because my users will solely depend on that to be able to edit the corresponding data - if they hover and no tooltip is rendered, clicking for edit does not work

Comment: The padding workaround looks cool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I think I found a hackish solution to this.

It seems to me this is a bug related to the fact that

`xAxis: {type: 'datetime'}`

pushes the first and last datapoint to the limits of the plot area (this doesn't happen when using `category`).

So the way around this problem is to create some padding using

```
x-axis: {
minPadding:0.02,
maxPadding:0.02
}
```

Then hover behaves correctly, similar to when x-axis is `category`.

Note that minPadding and maxPadding have to be > `0.02`. If you use `0.01` you'll have a buggy hover.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need in 'hack' - just use the latest version of Highcharts http://jsfiddle.net/WdVtE/

Comment: cheery, the video I captured was using v2.1.9, same one as your Fiddle - BTW your fiddle works just fine, as I said this is erratic behavior but I need HC to behave in a predictable way, so I'll stick to the hack

Comment: Do not look at the numbers at the beginning of js file - they are not the same. Compare them, for example, here http://www.diffnow.com/  and you will see the difference.